# Overloaded use of yield return

Tags: c#, yield

I don't have much experience with using the yield keyword.  I have these IEnumerable<T> extensions for Type Conversion.

My question is does the first overloaded method have the same yield return effect that I'm getting from the second method?

```
public static IEnumerable<TTo> ConvertFrom<TTo, TFrom>(this IEnumerable<TFrom> toList)
{
    return ConvertFrom<TTo, TFrom>(toList, TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TTo)));
}

public static IEnumerable<TTo> ConvertFrom<TTo, TFrom>(this IEnumerable<TFrom> toList, TypeConverter converter)
{
    foreach (var t in toList)
        yield return (TTo)converter.ConvertFrom(t);
}
```

Comment: I'll update re your comment to Jon...

Comment: Please, set up your comment as an answer in this thred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947919/template-style-is-not-setting-some-preferences and I mark it accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the first overload, it will immediately call the second overload. That won't execute any of the code in its body, which will have been moved into a nested class implementing the iterator block. When `GetEnumerator()` and then `MoveNext()` are first called on the returned `IEnumerable<TTo>`, *then* the code in your second overload will begin executing.

I have a fairly long [article on the iterator block implementation](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx), which you may find interesting.

Comment: Do you agree with @Marc Gravell?  the way I'm using this method is to translate an EF object into a DataContract object for WCF.  so List(Hotels).ConvertTo(SerializableHotels, Hotels)();

Comment: I have no firm opinion about type converters - but I know Marc knows a lot more about it than I do.

Comment: Actually, Jon - that sounds like a job for your property-mapper in MiscUtil (can't remember the name).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because **yield return** just generates an IEnumerator class on compile.  `yield return` is just compiler magic.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside... most type-converters only work to/from strings. Another interesting option here might be the static conversion operators defined against the type(s) - I have some .NET 3.5 code that does this in [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) - see the `Convert` method mentioned [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html).

Re your comment:

> the way I'm using this method is to
>   translate an EF object into a
>   DataContract object for WCF. so
>   List(Hotels).ConvertTo(SerializableHotels,
>   Hotels)()

It sounds like you should *either* be using serialization, or if the property names have a direct relationship, maybe something like `PropertyCopy<To>.CopyFrom(from)` - this is again from MiscUtil (but some of Jon's work this time) - i.e.

```
public static IEnumerable<TTo> ConvertFrom<TTo, TFrom>(
    this IEnumerable<TFrom> list, TypeConverter converter)
{
    return list.Select(item => PropertyCopy<TTo>.CopyFrom<TFrom>(item);
}
```

Other than that, you're probably better-off talking about a `Conversion<,>` rather than a `TypeConverter`.

Comment: Marc, this is great.  I'm not sure if I can use it due to some licensing issues.  I'll have to check but thanks

Comment: I'd like to give you the answer, because you answered my hidden un-asked question, and I thank you.  Although, the others answered the exact question that I asked about the usage of yield.  Thoughts?